# How to map a localhost application of azure to register365 domain

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure and register365(domain provider). I have deployed a node app on azure server which is running on a port 8092 and I have opened the port publicly so that app can be accessible to remote computers with public IP. Now I want to map this http://localhost:8092 to a Domain URL available on my register365 www.****.com. I am not able to go ahead with this. It would be really great if someone can provide their valuable guidance.

Thanks in Advance,
Yashpal Singh

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not programming-related, and fits better on SuperUser. That said: this question is confusing, as you mentioned using Azure Web Apps (or Web Sites as it was formerly called), which does not support ports other than 80 and 443. Maybe you deployed to a VM instead?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to map this http://localhost:8092 to a Domain URL available
>   on my register365 www.****.com.

As we know, we **can't** map port to domain name.

We can't map port 8092 to `www.****.com`.

We should map your domain name to your Azure server public IP address with **A record**(also we can use CNAME record), then when we access this app, we should use `www.****.com:8092`.

---

**Update:**

We can add **CNAME record** to your web app service like this:

```
Host          type                value
www           CNAME               xxx.cloudapp.azure.com
```

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I have done all the configuration now I am getting this message "took too long to respond." when hitting the URL.

Comment: @Yashpal Please use `nslookup` to check it, make sure you have map it correct:)  about nslookup, please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940085.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks Jason, I have done all the configuration from godaddy to route to specific ip and port where my application is deployed but the issue is that the port 8092 is not publicly accessible although I have updated the inbound rule in firewall setting for the same. Could  you please provide some valuable suggestion.

Comment: @Yashpal Sorry for the delay, as far as I know, we can't specify port for DNS, so you should browse your DNS name with port 8092. If it helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)